# Constructing a program-string for debugging C-code in/for launch.json

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to use vscode for debugging c-code on ubuntu. My buildsystem creates executable-files at a location that is pretty much constructed from the location and name of the .c file (e.g. `source/modules/module1/test/aspect_test.c` is built into `build/modules/module1/test/module1_aspect_test`).

I want to create a launch.json that runs the executable depending on the currently opened file.

My first thought was to create a task in task.json that sources a bash-script, which constructs the name and exports it a as environment-variable. I'm using this as an preLaunchTask.
I thought i can use the set environment variable for the program, but the variable is empty when used in launch.json with:

```
"program": "${env:execName}",
```

My next idea was to use inputs to call the script and use the output.

```
"inputs": [
    {
      "id": "execName",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "shellCommand.execute",
      "args": {
         "command": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/make_program_name.sh ${fileDirname}/${fileBasename}"
      }
    }
],
```

But here i run into the problem, that ${fileDirname}/${fileBasename} seem to be unset in the inputs.

The last way i tried is to use a file that is written by the script as preLaunchTask and read in inputs:

```
"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "execName",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
        "args": {
        "fileName": "/tmp/execName.txt"
        }
    }
],
```

which works, but i don't really like it.

Is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Comment: what kind of weird scheme do you have of placing the exe file relative to the c file

Comment: is it that weird? Code is placed in something like source/modules/module1/test/aspect_test.c which is built into build/modules/module1/test/module1_aspect_test . Maybe my description above is not correct?

Comment: if you don't mention it in the question we can only guess the weirdness

Comment: I thought "My buildsystem creates executable-files at a location that is pretty much constructed from the location and name of the .c file." would describe it enough to understand the question and the actual example wouldn't really matter. I'll add the example.

Comment: is the exe name really `module1_aspect_test`? It is already in a subdir `module1`

Comment: Yes it is. I guess it was helpful in test-reports to do it like this

Comment: why don't you show `make_program_name.sh` how it constructs the exe filename

Comment: Because I hoped for a more general answer, not tailored to the actual construction. In my mind the construction of the name didn't really matter, but your answer using transform shows, that it kind of does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `transform` command from the Command Variable extension

```json
"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "execName",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
        "args": {
          "text": "${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
          "find": "^source",
          "replace": "build"
        }
    }
]
```

If you want variable subst in the `inputs` part you can use

```json
"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "execName",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
        "args": {
          "text": "${command:execName}"
          "command": {
            "execName": {
              "variableSubstArgs": true,
              "command": "shellCommand.execute",
              "args": {
                "command": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/make_program_name.sh ${fileDirname}/${fileBasename}"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Your second example would be very nice, but i can't get it to work. It executes the script and shows the correct path, but then the debugging is just stuck (moving bar below RUN AND DEBUG) with no way to cancel.

Comment: @michael199316  follow the C/C++ debug instructions on the VSC C/C++-doc page **exactly**, also try the tutorial

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to in the tutorial/instructions. The debugging itself usually works when called with e.g. the „inputs“ from file mentioned in the question. It only gets stuck when I try your suggested “inputs“. I think maybe the structure of using transform as tool to call a different command doesn't work? Have you successfully used it before? I would prefer this to the file input way I currently use.

Comment: @michael199316  what happens if you use this input in a simple shell echo statement to see what the result of the input is, see [issue 50](https://github.com/rioj7/command-variable/issues/50) tcm has used this construct

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works now. Sadly I don't know what changed or caused the deadlock.